# It's been a while hasn't it?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking, acrostic, affix-riddle

Why can't I say hello? Anyways, it's Emma!

> I know it's been a while, but I've been busy with work, and life, and I haven't had much free time lately.

With that in mind though, I've got a new puzzle!

> Missing?
>
> I need a moment.
>
> See I've been here before; yes, before I do say.
>
> Such a wonderful place, a quick Riley to play!
>
> E? Thee? The prefix to awn, the circular infix is unseen at dawn.
>
> Dipped, no curved, the suffix is uh, the prefix to prefix this run-on, well duh.

It sounded difficult when I wrote it, but I think **you** got it!

---

What am I trying to say?

Comment: Okay... Why can't I start my post with `Hey everyone!`?...

Comment: I assume this is an [enigmatic-puzzle]? As in, it's not immediately clear what kind of puzzle it is... at least, it isn't clear to me what has to be done to get the answer. Or is is a [riddle]? Would [affix-riddle] (the Riley-riddle tag) be applicable?

Comment: @bobble actually, now that I think about it, adding the proper tags to describe each part of the puzzle available doesn't really make it entirely simplistic. Some lateral thinking is still involved, but the bright minds here will prove me wrong and solve it faster now I'm sure lol

Comment: Also, when did we create the `affix-riddle` tag? I know at one point we said we didn't need a tag for that as it fit into wordplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are saying

> I missed you

Because

> the first letters of the first two sections spell I missed and "you" is bolded.

The title

> also points to this.  It's been a while!